# Convert existing intranet into Visual Studio .sln project file

Tags: html, visual-studio, publish, intranet

I am trying to move our intranet folder and files into a visual studio .sln file so that we can publish using Visual Studio's tools. Currently, we use Visual Studio to edit the files and WebMatrix 3.0 to publish them. WebMatrix has been in EOL for a few years and I am unable to configure it successfully on a new PC. The intranet files are stored on a network drive and then they get published to an IIS web server.

Is it as simple as creating a blank project and copying the top level folder into that directory?

Is there a specific project type I need to create? Is there a way to figure out?

Is this even possible?

Using: Visual Studio 2019 16.9.6

Comment: No. In most cases you cannot migrate things (like PHP based) in WebMatrix to VS, unless your projects were .NET based. Take a look at VSCode, as that tool is more suitable for folder based file editing.

Comment: I do not think it's PHP based but I'm not sure how to check. What's the difference between VS and VSCode? I thought they were very similar/minor differences.

Comment: Also, the code is edited in Visual Studio already, I just need to get it under a .sln file in order to use the publish feature.

Comment: Do you have any project files? A solution is just a group of projects. You need to sort out the situation with projects first. Once that's done, you can create a new empty solution and add the projects into it.

Comment: There are currently no project files. It is simply a folder with the page files within it.